# Share in a layout

Tags: android, android-sharing

Is it possible to send data, like an audio file, to WhatsApp or the like in a kind of layout? Something like the "layout" you get when sharing a YouTube video on WhatsApp:

[image]

What I'm thinking right now is that this maybe isn't a layout that sends with the data but WhatsApp or other apps recognize the YouTube link and add the layout to it themselves. Is this correct?

At the moment my code for sharing audio files is common and looks like this:

```
final String AUTHORITY = view.getContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";

Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(view.getContext(), AUTHORITY, file);

final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
shareIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
view.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share sound via..."));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I don't think that it works. You can send a Text via WhatsApp. Maybe this will help when you want to send a Text via WhatsApp, too: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012
But a whole layout or Audio...I don't think that we have the abilities to do that.